# Pandas, selecting first oberservation of a group and sort

Tags: python, pandas

New to pandas and trying to get better.  I would like to group_by the "id" column, then order_by "col2" then "col3", then take the top observation.
Thanks in advance

```
  In[5]:df
  Out[5]:
            id         col2         col3
  0         1           2            5 
  1         1           2            2 
  2         2           8            3 
  3         2           3            6  
  4         2           3            1 
  5         1           3            7 
  6         2           5            6 
  7         1           8            6
```

Desired:

```
  In[6]:df_selection
  Out[6]:
            id         col2         col3
  0         1           2            2 
  1         2           3            1
```

Answer (score 1):

A very short way to do this would be to sort by these columns, group, and take the first of each group:

```
>>> df.sort_values(by=['col2', 'col3']).groupby('id').first()
    col2    col3
id      
1   2   2
2   3   1
```

To get the exact output as your question, just reset the index:

```
>>> df.sort_values(by=['col2', 'col3']).groupby('id').first().reset_index()
    id  col2    col3
0   1   2   2
1   2   3   1
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it works!  Just a curiosity question, how would I pass an argument to sort by ascending/descending?

Comment: @nonegiven72 Through the [`ascending` keyword](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) :-) It takes a bool or list of bools.